# Graphical interpretation of discontinuity of second derivative at a given point

Tags: calculus, continuity

Is there a known graphical interpretation of the fact that $f''_+(0)\not= f_-''(0)$ ?
I encountered this problem when trying to graph the function $f$ defined as follows :

$\begin{cases} f(x) = xe^x-x \quad , x≤0 \\
f(x)=(1+x)e^\tfrac{-1}{x} \quad , x>0 \end{cases}$

I found $f''_+(0)=0$ and $f''_{-}(0)=2$

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

$$$$
$$$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really appear until you graph the first derivative.

[image: Graph of function and derivatives]

Here the left and right hand side (respectively) are the left and right hand derivatives. There you can see that the left side is approaching a higher value than the right hand side, ergo a discontinuity in the second derivatives.

Pretty cool example!